# Prove $T\left(x,T(y,z)\right)=T(T(x,y),z)$

Tags: normed-spaces, associativity

Given
$$T_m(x,y)=\min(x,y),$$
for all $x,y\in[0,1]$.

Prove $T_m\left(x,T_m(y,z)\right)=T_m(T_m(x,y),z)$.

\begin{align*}
  T_m\left(x,T_m(y,z)\right)&=\min(x,T_m(y,z))\\
  &=\min(x,\min(y,z))
\end{align*}

Is it right the proof as below?
\begin{align*}
T_m\left(x,T_m(y,z)\right)&=\min(x,y,z)\\
&=\min(\min(x,y),z)\\
&=T_m(T_m(x,y),z).
\end{align*}

Comment: Of course, we know that $min$ and $max$ are associative, so....

Comment: Why does $\min(x,y,z)=\min(x,\min(y,z))$?